# How to effectively parse and evaluate a bit-string expression with L/R SHIFT, L/R CIRC, AND, XOR, and OR?

Tags: python, parsing, bitstring

In class, we just started to learn about bit-string flicking, starting from the basic functions: LSHIFT, RSHIFT, LCIRC, RCIRC, AND, XOR, OR.  Then, suddenly, we were given the task of writing a python program that would parse and evaluate a bit-string expression.  While I find it fairly straightforward to solve bit-string expressions by hand, I don't have any good grasp on an efficient way to parse and evaluate a bit-string expression through python.  I have defined all of the required functions below, which work for single operator expressions (i.e. LCIRC 4 0010), but as of now, I am completely stuck on how to parse multi-operator expressions (i.e. LCIRC 3 LCIRC 3 0010).

```
import collections 
commands = ["LCIRC","RCIRC"] 
i = 0 
parse = input("Enter a string here to be evaluated. Use bitstrings only, as this program cannot catch any exceptions otherwise. -->").upper().replace("AND","&").replace("OR","|").replace("XOR","^").replace("NOT","~").split(" ") 
#parsing the function 

def lcirc(circ,operand): 
    circ = int(parse[i+1]) 
    operand = list(parse[i-1]) 
    parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i); 
    length = len(operand) 
    circ = circ % length 
    operand = operand[circ % length:]+ operand[:circ % length]                       
    operand = "".join(operand) 
    return operand 

def rcirc(Rcirc,operand): 
    Rcirc = int(parse[i+1]) 
    operand = list(parse[i-1]) 
    parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i); 
    length = len(operand) 
    Rcirc = Rcirc % length 
    operand = operand[-Rcirc % length:]+ operand[:-Rcirc % length]                       
    operand = "".join(operand) 
    return operand

def rshift(shift,operand): 
    shift = parse[i+1] 
    operand = list(parse[i+2]) 
    parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i); 
    print(operand) 
    length = len(operand) 
    if int(shift) >= len(operand): 
        for a in range(0,len(operand)): 
            operand.insert(0,"0") 
    if int(shift) < len(operand): 
        for a in range(0,int(shift)):
            operand.insert(0,"0") 
    operand = operand[:length] 
    operand = "".join(operand) 
    return operand 

def lshift(shift,operand):
    shift = parse[i+1]
    operand = list(parse[i+2])
    parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i);parse.pop(i);
    length = len(operand)
    if int(shift) >= len(operand):
        for a in range(0,len(operand)):
            operand.insert(length,"0")
    if int(shift) < len(operand):
        for a in range(0,int(shift)):
            operand.insert(length,"0")
    operand = operand[-length:]
    operand = "".join(operand)
    return operand

def and(op1, op2): #operand1, operand2
    return str(bin(int(op1,2) & int(op2,2))).replace("0b","")

def xor(op1, op2): #operand1, operand2
    return str(bin(int(op1,2) ^ int(op2,2))).replace("0b","")

def or(op1, op2): #operand1, operand2
    return str(bin(int(op1,2) | int(op2,2))).replace("0b","")

def evaluate(): 
    #parsing and evaluating the expression, insert code here.
    i = 0


while True: 
    if "LCIRC" not in parse and "RCIRC" not in parse and "RSHIFT" not in parse and "LSHIFT" not in parse and "~" not in parse and "|" not in parse and "&" not in parse and "^" not in parse: 
        break 
    else: 
        evaluate() 

print("Your answer is --> " +"".join(parse))
```

This program should be able to take input such as:

```
>>> LCIRC 1 0010
>>> Your answer is --> 0100
>>> LCIRC 1 LCIRC 1 0010
>>> Your answer is 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand your problem statement correctly (should the second sample output be 1000?), I can think of two ways to solve the problem:

1) Evaluate right to left. If you are only ever looking at single variate function calls as with the circular shifts, you should do fine to simply evaluate the innermost (rightmost) expression first.

2) Use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science). This would basically take the form of something like the following (pardon the pseudo-code).

```
def handleExpression(str):
    #assuming str is of form of parse
    #if two sided operator
    if(typeof str[0] == number)
        #Find base operator and the two expressions which represent its arguments.
        #^^Format the arguments in the form of parse
        #(You can think of this in terms of parentheses: for every open parenthesis, you need a closing parenthesis.
        #So, you can just keep track of open and close "parentheses" until you reach an operand with a balance of "parentheses")
        operation = #xor, and, etc.
        return operation(handleExpression(leftSide), handleExpression(rightSide))
    else #some kind of shift
        #whatever code
```

Obviously, I left a ton of holes in this code, but after all isn't this an assignment? :) I hope this helps you get started thinking about how this could work.

Comment: Wups.  Yeah it should be 1000.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a task for either recursion or [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

My simple approach, using string [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method with maxsplit argument:

```
def evaluate(s):
    cmd, arg1, arg2 = s.split(None, 2)
    if ' ' in arg2:
        arg2 = evaluate(arg2)
    return command(arg1, arg2) # TODO: call correct function with correct arguments

def command(a1, a2):
    print a1, a2
```

Comment: Thanks, but the only problem with reverse polish notation (postfix) or polish notation (prefix) is that not the entire expression can be represented using postfix or prefix.  For example, LCIRC 1 00010 is prefix, but LCIRC 1 00010 & 00100 is not a valid prefix, infix, or postfix expression.